# check if SSH reverse tunnel endpoint is forwarding to port that is already listening

Tags: ssh, tcp, netcat, ssh-tunnel

I have started reverse SSH tunnel on host1:

```
host1@host1:~ $ while true; do echo "$(date) - Tunnel created" && ssh host2@host2 -NT -R3389:localhost:3389; done
```

I can check if port that I'm reverse tunneling from host2 is opened using following command:

```
host2@host2:~$ nc -zv host1 3389
nc: connect to host1 port 3389 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

But if I issue following command then It (probably) checks status of the port on localhost. Which in fact is opened:

```
host2@host2:~$ nc -zv localhost 3389
Connection to localhost 3389 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

But I want to check status of the port on other site of the SSH tunnel. So previous command should return that the port is closed until I issue following:

```
host1@host1:~/.ssh $ while true; do nc -lp 3389; done
```

Is this even possible due to nature of TCP?

Answer (score 1):

You **CAN NOT use TCP proxy approach to simulate absense of service ("connection refused")** at proxy entry(host2) point because:

1. it(proxy service) can not know whether service at target(host1) is
   stopped or not until it try to connect.
2. proxy works at much higher layer than such simulation requires

Your client  already established connection to the proxy so the only possible way for proxy to terminate connection is to do connection reset (while real target's behavior would be "connection refused" or "timed out" ).

So nothing can't be done to simulate absence of service by using TCP proxy approach.

***real world proxy behavior (what you have)***

```
Client        Proxy                       target
 ----HND-F1-SYN-->|                           |
 <---HND-F2-------|                           |
 ----HND-F3------>|                           |
                  |---second hop connectopn-->|
```

***ideal proxy's behavior (which you want)***

```
Client        Proxy                       target
 ----HND-F1-SYN-->|                           |
                  |---second hop connectopn-->|
 <---HND-F2-------|                           |
 ----HND-F3------>|                           |
```

Well, of course **you could craft solution to simulate absence of target service** by keeping two listening sockets (raw + generic) while using firewall to do special processing for incoming SYN frame, i.e.:

- iptables reroutes SYN frame to the raw socket listener service
- raw socket listener svc establishes second hop connection to target service
- [on connection failure] raw listener responds with crafted RST frame to simulated CONNREFUSED - i.e. absence of service.
- [on connection success] raw listener re-injects SYN frame to be delivered to proxy service listener and associates already established second hop connection with client connection (which is still at handshake phase)

As you can see it could be easy to implement such solution but it would not be popular because it requires the use of promiscuous sockets and requires extra load on CPU.
Well, that was an explanation for Why it is not possible.

**And here is how you can do it the way you want:**

- You can build virtual bridge (use openvswitch)
- and use iptables to route all frames destination host.

This way connection between host1 and host2 will be secure and your client will see absolutely identical handshakes at TCP level and thus it will know for sure whether service is running (successful connection) or not (connrefused or timedout).